# Facebook connect button with custom image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to use custom image for Facebook connect button.
Here's standard code from Facebook:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=486357154765214";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

To display button:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

Any idea?

Cheers guys!

Comment: Use your own button, and use the JS SDK to handle login upon click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Add your own button image and on "onclick" event call FB.login method. More details about FB.login here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: Thank you guys. What would be the line of code for onclick event?